# HTML Email Signature Outlook Adding Padding

Tags: html, css

I've created an HTML email signature which looks perfectly fine in the browser and when sent though Chrome but when I paste the signature into Outlook, the cell padding style is getting removed.

So `<td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">` becomes `<td style="margin: 0px;'>` which is creating a gap around my image.

Is there some way around this?